# Security policy

Tags: java

Можно ли через Java Security policy, как то ограничить бесконечные циклы? Или как с этим бороться?

Comment: С бесконечными циклами надо бороться правильной их разработкой.

Comment: Через загрущик классов надо запускать разные классы и там может быть вредительство.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, в теории языков задача определения бесконечного цикла является неразрешимой.

Альтернативные варианты:

1) Можно обернуть задачу в другой поток, поставить timeout на нее и кидать `InterruptedExecption`;

2) Можно делать fork-процесса, поставить timeout на получение результата от процесса и делать `kill -15`.

Comment: Кинуть InterruptedException кому? Его же нельзя просто так взять и создать в коде стороннего треда.

Comment: Колличество цыклов CPU подсчитать ?

Comment: @etki, создать нельзя, но мы имеем ссылку на поток выполнения, поэтому может просто прервать поток через `Thread.interrupt()`. Хотя сторонний поток может перехватывать это и игнорировать. С процессами OC ситуация лучше в плане прерывания.

Comment: @TomX01, количество циклов через java не подсчитать насколько мне известно. Тут скорее всего будет решение, зависимое от платформы, которое требует low-level кода и вызова через JNI. Также не совсем ясно, чем подсчет количества циклов от timeout отличается.

Comment: @TomX01, если была мысль по поводу подсчета точного количества циклов для кода, то задача неразрешима без самого запуска кода.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться статическим анализатором кода для поиска явных безконечных циклов.

Можно посмотреть в сторону [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) или [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/).